# Remove /public/ from url in codeigniter 4, but redirect function still throw to /public/

Tags: php, redirect, configuration, url-rewriting, codeigniter-4

I changed my CI4 project configuration to remove /public/index.php from the url, and after that, the project can be accessed without that url. However, if I redirect the url using the redirect()->to('contoller) function, it still redirects to projectname/public/controller.

For example, suppose I access "projectname/admin", if not logged in, I should be redirected to "projectname/login", but instead of being redirected to that address, I was redirected to  "projectname/public/login"

I did a test by disabling the element in the public folder, (renamed), and it changed to 404 after the redirect and says

> "Controller or its method is not found:
> \App\Controllers\Public::login"

Is there anything that would need to be changed again regarding the removal of public from the url?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs.
If you want to remove it.

1. Check mod_rewrite extension enabled in apache.
2. update your .htaccess file with following code.

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

More information can be found here.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html